# Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 128

Tags: c#, excel, winapp

Mine is C# windows application.
When i run this application in my local machine it gives following error:-
"Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 128".

```C#
try
{
    string path = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("E:\\09-2013\\SalesRep\\Openleads.xlsx");
    if (Path.GetExtension(path) == ".xls")
    {
        oledbConn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; 
        Data Source=" + path + "Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"");
    }
    else if (Path.GetExtension(path) == ".xlsx")
    {
        oledbConn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; 
        Data Source=" + path + "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';");
    }

    oledbConn.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(); ;
    OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    cmd.Connection = oledbConn;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Raw Data$]";
    oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    oleda.Fill(ds, "dsSlno");
    grvData.DataSource = ds.Tables["dsSlno"].DefaultView;
    oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    oleda.Fill(ds);

    grvData.DataSource = ds.Tables[1].DefaultView;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
finally
{
    oledbConn.Close();
}
```

Comment: where does it raise this error?

Comment: @RowlandShaw: While executing the following line, am getting this error. 
oledbConn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + path + "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';");
Now I have changed this line as 
oledbConn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + path + "Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"");

Even though am getting the same with small modification. 
It has been changed as “Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 121”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your path needs an @ sign in the front of it to escape your backslashes:

There is a null-terminating character (\0) after the 'E:' in it causing your issue when it's concatenated to your connection string.

Change this:

`string path = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath("E:\09-2013\SalesRep\Openleads.xlsx");`

To this:

`string path = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@"E:\09-2013\SalesRep\Openleads.xlsx");`

And you should be fine.