# Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 121

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

On this button click it should load the contents of an excel file into a dataGrid but instead am getting the error mentioned in the title of this post. What is it that am doing wrong?

```
 private void button7_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        string path = "C:\\Users\\jdavis\\Downloads\\Pharmacies\\CrossReferencing v3\\CrossReferencing\\\bin\\Debug\\cross_check.xls";
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = " + path + ";Extended Properties=' Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;';");
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand
        (
            "SELECT"+"FROM [cross_check]",con

        );
        DataSet cross = new DataSet();
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
        adapter.Fill(cross);
        dataGridView2.DataSource = cross.Tables[0];



    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 128](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636261/format-of-the-initialization-string-does-not-conform-to-specification-starting-a)

Comment: Have you tried putting quotes around your path?
Source = \"" + path + "\";Extended

Comment: @PeterB He is escaping his backslashes, so I don't think this is a duplicate.

Comment: @PeterB it ain't a duplicate. Completely different

Comment: @vipersassassin same thing

Comment: @vipersassassin it now says "could not find installable ISAM."

at this line: `adapter.Fill(cross);`

Comment: @Jevon you have an extra slash between bin and CrossReferencing

Comment: @vipersassassin Thanks for that but still the same thing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127726/discussion-between-vipersassassin-and-jevon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the values as shown below, and this will get the ISAM and formatting issues fixed.

```
string path = " \"C:\\Users\\jdavis\\Downloads\\Pharmacies\\CrossReferencing v3\\CrossReferencing\\bin\\Debug\\cross_check.xls\" ";
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties= Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;");
```